# Bind mount points populating very quickly

Tags: centos, mount, bind

I've got more and more bind mount points: http://pastebin.com/susp4ryL

```
ls -l /dev/root
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 mar  7 19:24 /dev/root -> /dev/md1
```

How to fix this ? It really slows down yum.

I'm on CentOS 5.7 64-bit, latest default kernel 2.6.18-274.18.1.el5

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to remove /etc/init.d/named start from one of my cronjobs.